# How to position Frames and make them dynamic for windowchanges

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and i want to create a dynamic GUI that changes with changed window size.

so here are my first steps:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

from tkinter import *


#tkinter Fenster setzen
root = tk.Tk()
user = ctypes.windll.user32

#Parameter setzen
window_width    = int(user.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 2) 
window_height   = int(user.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 2)
s = 'Fensterauflösung = ' + str(user.GetSystemMetrics(0)) + 'x' + str(user.GetSystemMetrics(1))

#Framewerte
top_framex = (window_width/4)
top_framey = int(window_height*(1/8))
left_framex = int(top_framex*2)
left_framey = int(window_height*(7/8))

screen_center_x = 0
screen_center_y = 0 

#Fensterposition festlegen
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{screen_center_x}+{screen_center_y}')

#Frames
top_frame  = tk.Frame(root,width = window_width, height = top_framey, bg='red').grid(row=0, column =0,columnspan = 4)
left_frame = tk.Frame(root,width = left_framex, height = left_framey, bg='blue').grid(row=1, column =0)

#Labels
label1 = Label(top_frame, text=window_width,bg='green').grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = Label(left_frame, text="Left Frame",bg='green').grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

My first problem is the position of the blue Frame.

Even if I wrote column=0 like for the red frame the starting position doesn't fit.

My second problem is the label1. What do I have to do to align it with the frame? Or is it aligned and the position of the blue Frame is right but the red Frame is wrong?

Last question: my Idea for making the GUI dynamic is getting the window size and changing the frame sizes/positions on that.Is this the right way ?

After the nice answer it works now :

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

from tkinter import *


#tkinter Fenster setzen
root = tk.Tk()
user = ctypes.windll.user32

#Parameter setzen
window_width    = int(user.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 2) 
window_height   = int(user.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 2)
s = 'Fensterauflösung = ' + str(user.GetSystemMetrics(0)) + 'x' + str(user.GetSystemMetrics(1))

#Framewerte
top_framex = (window_width/4)
top_framey = int(window_height*(1/8))
left_framex = int(top_framex*2)
left_framey = int(window_height*(6/8))

screen_center_x = 0
screen_center_y = 0 

#Fensterposition festlegen
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{screen_center_x}+{screen_center_y}')

#Frames
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#top_frame  = tk.Frame(root,width = window_width, height = top_framey, bg='red').grid()
top_frame  = tk.Frame(root,bg='red')
top_frame.place(relheight = 0.2, relwidth = 1)
left_frame = tk.Frame(root,width = left_framex, height = left_framey, bg='blue')
left_frame.place(rely=0.2, relheight = 0.8, relwidth = 0.5)

#Labels
label1 = Label(top_frame, text="Top Frame",bg='green')
label1.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)
label2 = Label(left_frame, text="Left Frame",bg='green')
label2.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that `top_frame` and `left_frame` are `None` because they are result of `grid(...)`.  Therefore both the labels are in the root window, not in the two frames you expected.

Comment: thx for that hint!